# What is the abstraction logic to translate NoSQL Exceptions to Spring Data?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

In Spring Framework about the abstraction of error codes specific for the known RDBMS - it for **SQL** world and **even** without matter the mechanism of persistence such as JPA, JDBC, Hibernate - exists the [sql-error-codes.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml) file.

Therefore Spring uses those codes for translation purposes to the [DataAccessException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html) hierarchy according to the error thrown from the RDBMS.

How is accomplished the same **abstraction** to reach goal for **NoSQL**? It for the umbrella of the `Spring Data` projects. Of course, here now is specific for each different technology such as MongoDB, Couchbase, Neo4j but is assumed there is a global and generic abstraction logic without matter the mechanism of persistence.